# MYSQL/PHP - Select all columns from table records distincting by one column

Tags: php, mysql, distinct, fetch

I'm a bit confused about `DISTINCT` keyword. Let's guess that this query will get all the records distincting the columns set in the query:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people";
```

Now, that query is fetching all the records distincting column "name" and at the same time only fetching "name" column. How I'm supposed to ONLY distinct one column and at the same time get all the desired columns?

This would be the scheme:

*NEEDED COLUMNS*

- name
- surname
- age

*DISTINCTING COLUMNS*

- name

What would be the correct sintaxis for that query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is distinct across all columns you fetch. So if two people have the same name and age, but different surname, you will get two rows. What is the expected result here? If my example happens, which surname do you want to get?

Comment: So easy as:  `SELECT DISTINCT(name), surname, age FROM people` ?

Comment: @Riad It's working with static defined columns, but giving mysql error when using "all" selector "*". Ideas? Thank you.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The expected result is to get all the records from a table but not duplicated ones by a column. I didn't set the column as a unique key when defined the table because the table itself is used to store  duplicated records and then process them.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. If you have two rows: `name1, surname1, age1` and `name1, surname2, age1`, if you then want distinct on `firstname`, which of the two rows would you expect? The one with `surname1` or `surname2`? And the same question goes in case the `age` value also differs.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It's irrelevant in my case. I just want to get the column from the record but I want to fetch only one row for each duplicated column. I'm expecting this because once I have the record, I know the person with name X is on the list and they it may be more records from that person in particular. Maybe there's a better way to do this and this may be totally wrong but it's where I got to. Thank you.

Comment: "that person"? Isn't `name1 surname1` and `name1 surname2` two different people? Well, I don't really get what you want from your explanations so I can't be of further help, I'm afraid... Good luck though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row per name, then a normal method is an aggregation query:

```
select name, max(surname) as surname, max(age) as age
from t
group by name;
```

MySQL supports an extension of the `group by`, which allows you to write a query such as:

```
select t.*
from t
group by name;
```

I strongly recommend that you do *not* use this.  It is non-standard and the values come from *indeterminate* matching rows.  There is not even a guarantee that they come from the same row (although they typically do in practice).

Often, you want something like that biggest age.  If so, you handle this differently:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.age = (select max(t2.age) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

Note:  This doesn't use `group by`.  And, it will return duplicates if there are multiple rows with the same age.

Another method uses variables -- another MySQL-specific feature.  But, if you are still learning about `select`, you should probably wait to learn about variables.

Comment: Thanks for answering! So DISTINCT keyworkd won't be useful for what I'm looking for, right? If I understood your answer, your recommended technique is to manually group the records by getting the max record for a certain column.